# remove ActionLink text n MVC 4 if the list row does not have a value to link to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a standard list in a view. Each row has an actionlink call ViewSubalert. but not every record has sub or child alerts, so I want to hide the actionlink that does not have an underlying value.

View Sub Alert  an alert
                another alert
View Sub Alert  another alert

This was pretty easy in a Gridview using web forms but not sure how to do it in MVC 4.
Action link snytax:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Sub Alerts", "Index","SubAlerts", new { id = item.AlertID }, new { 
 @class = "SubAlertModalOpener" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Render it conditionally

```
@if( HasSubAlert == true)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("View Sub Alerts", "Index","SubAlerts", new { id = item.AlertID }, new {  @class = "SubAlertModalOpener @"})
}
```

or

(I have not tested it):

You can add `style = "@( condition ? string.empty : "display:none")"` in the HTML Attributes, Like

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Sub Alerts", "Index","SubAlerts", new { id = item.AlertID }, new {  @class = "SubAlertModalOpener @",  style = @( condition ? string.empty : "display:none")  })
```

Comment: Is the HasSubAlert an actionresult in the controller? where in the controller I would check to see if an item exists for the current row in the for loop?